# How to print a string AFTER the date in Linux Terminal?

Tags: linux, date, terminal, echo, xargs

I want to type a one-line command in Linux that will print the date followed by a string to the Terminal. For example, "... is today's date." This is what I tried.

```
MyComputer:~ me$ date | xargs echo " is today's date."
```

However, this printed " is today's date. Sat Feb 20..."

I thought reversing the order would help, but this only printed the date.

```
MyComputer:~ me$ echo " is today's date." | date | xargs echo
```

Conversely, my third attempt only printed " is today's date." without the date.

```
MyComputer:~ me$ date | xargs echo | echo " is today's date."
```

I am out of ideas. Short of multiple commands, using file input, or even paraphrasing it as "Today's date is..." how can I get my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "`date` is today's date."
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `echo` to interpolate between fixed strings and command calls:

```
edd@rob:~$ echo "Today is $(date) and I feel fine"
Today is Sat Feb 20 01:15:02 PM CST 2021 and I feel fine
edd@rob:~$
```

Strictly speaking this uses the (`bash` for me) shell to run the command before passing its output to `echo`.  Instead of `$(date)` you could also use backticks.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the date into a variable and then echo the date and additional text:

```
YourComputer:~ me$ Now=$(date +"%m-%d-%y") | echo "$Now is today's date"
```

Where "Now" is the name of your date variable,
(date +"%m-%d-%y") prints the (formatted) date,
$Now is the echo-ed with your additional text.

Comment: (addendum: works/tested on Bash-Shell and zsh)